# regex replace words except in hyperlinks

Tags: php, regex

I have created a php function to replace the words I want to highlight in a text. The only problem I have is that input text can also be some html code. This causes existing hyperlinks to break.

```
public static function addLinks($text) {

    $array_of_words = array("this", "is", "a", "test");

    //replace the array_of_words with hyperlinks
    $pattern = '#(?<=^|\W)('. implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $array_of_words)) . ')(?=$|\W)#i';
    $callback = function ($match) {
        return "<a href=" . url('search') . "?search=" . urlencode($match[0]) . ">" . $match[0] . "</a>";
    };
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $text);
}
```

Question; Is it possible to use the regex function on a piece of html code, but make an exception for the a element? Otherwise the html code is not formatted correctly.

Comment: Don't try to parse HTML with regular expressions. Use a DOM parser library like `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Add `<a\s+[^<]*>[^<]*</a>(*SKIP)(*F)|` at the start of your pattern.